# RSpec + Capybara + Devise: current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

- rails (5.1.4)
- rspec-rails (3.7.2)
- capybara (2.16.1)
- devise (4.3.0)

I'm trying to create a RSpec Rails 3.7 System spec as in https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/system-specs/system-spec .

Additionally I want to apply the Devise authorization. I followed the instruction https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

But I guess it's kind of a defective implementation. I don't get the `current_user` method (which is `nil`).

Here my simple spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "testing system", type: :system do

  it "tests the spec" do

    admin = create(:admin) # user-admin

    login_as(admin, :scope => :admin)

    visit root_path

    click_link 'Home'

    save_and_open_page

  end
end
```

Since the code on my site depends heavily on the `current_user` value, I don't get a properly formed saved page (it looks like a user did not log in).

What should I do? Should I try to simply manually (somehow?) assign a value to `current_user`? Or maybe the https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara strategy is mainly defective and should be substituted to something more full-fledged technology?

I already tried to make

```
current_user = admin
```

in my code - but with no result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The devise wiki is correct for how to test while shortcutting logins, and no you can't just set `current_user`  in your test code (nor can you access it since it's only set inside the request).  Generally assume the error is in your usage of a gem, rather than a widely used and highly tested gem being defective.

With the description you've given there could be any number of reasons for it not actually logging in the user however the two most likely culprits are

1. Do you actually have multiple scopes configured in Devise? or should it just be `login_as(admin, :scope => :user)`  # equivalent to just login_as(admin)
2. Is `puma` running your tests in single mode, or clustered mode? (You may need to disable the silencing of puma output rspec-rails does by default -https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/95f4522c0549a32de59c19eb9b5f9a72126a9eb6/lib/rspec/rails/example/system_example_group.rb#L72 - to see that in the test output) If it's not in single mode then the app is being run in a separate process than the tests which means Devise can't actually shortcircuit the login, and you need to fix the puma config.

Comment: Yes, the problem was about `login_as(admin, :scope => :user)` and `login_as(admin)` works too. Just the Devise documentation was not clear enough. And, of course, I don't need to access `current_user` inside my spec - I need it to work only inside the code being tested. Thanks.